# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in 

Tags: php

This is my current code:

```
$directory = "polls/";
$dir = opendir($directory);

while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false {

  $filename = $directory . $file;
  $type = filetype($filename);
  if ($type == 'file') {
     $contents = file_get_contents($filename);
     $items = explode('¬', $contents);
     echo '<table width="500" border="1" cellpadding="4">';
     foreach ($items as $item) {
       echo "<tr><td>$item</td></tr>\n";
     }
     echo '</table>';
  }
}
closedir($dir);
```

For some reason this line is giving me an error:

```
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false {

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Balance your parentheses:

```
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
```

Answer (score 3):

it should be

```
while (($file = readdir($dir)) !== false) {
```